# How to save syslog severity <132> to a different file?

Tags: centos-6, syslog

We have an old appliance that sends syslog with severity <132> to its management server.

To capture said events the previous team created a tcpdump script and ran it via crontab to capture the events.

I'm trying to figure out how to get those events written to different file via syslog.

The syslog config is currently default config, I enabled the UDP capture module but I am unable to get it to write to a different file.

```
*.* /var/log/syslog_capture_all
:msg, contains, "[ApplianceModel]" /var/tmp/events_syslog
```

The first file has all the logs from system now and the second file is still emtpy.

The logs sent by the apliance are as follows as seen on the tcpdump saved file:

```
<132>[ApplianceModel] [Parameter=Parameter value] ......
```

I just want the "<132>[ApplianceModel] [Parameter=Parameter value] ......" to save to the /var/tmp/events_syslog file and get rid of that tcpdump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the input is not in a standard syslog format, attempts to parse it by syslog may not have put the string `ApplianceModel` into the `msg` property, so you will not match against it. If you are using rsyslog you could try the `rawmsg-after-pri` property instead.  Alternatively, you could match on the priority of 132, as in `:pri, isequal, "132"`.